# If $H$ has maximum vertex degree at most $3$ and is a minor of $G$, then $H$ is a topological minor of $G$.

Tags: graph-theory, graph-minors

> If  $H$ has maximum vertex degree at most $3$ (so $\Delta(H)\leq 3$) and $H$ is a minor of $G$, then $H$ is a topological minor of $G$.

The converse follows by definition. However, most sources state this proposition without a proof. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If $H$ is a minor, then there is some sequence of edge/vertex deletions and edge contractions that will take us from $G$ to $H$.

On the other hand, to show that $H$ is a *topological* minor, we need to show that there is a subdivision of $H$ that is isomorphic to a subgraph of $G$. This means that $H$ can be obtained from $G$ by a sequence of edge/vertex deletions, and then contraction of edges, but only contracting edges of the form $(u,v)$ where one of the vertices $u$ or $v$ has degree exactly $2$.

When forming $H$ from $G$ as a (regular) minor, we can do this so as to perform all edge/vertex deletions first to obtain a graph $G^\prime$. Notice that while we might want to later contract an edge $(x,y)$ where one of $x$ and $y$ have degree $1$, we can convert this operation to just deleting that degree $1$ vertex, and so we do this here instead.

In other words, we can first construct a graph $G^\prime$ by vertex/edge deletions that contains $H$ as a minor, such that $H$ is obtained from $G^\prime$ by contracting edges $(u,v)$ where both $u,v$ have degree at least $2$.

If $G^\prime=H$, then we're done. Otherwise we need to perform some edge contractions. The key point here is that if $\Delta(H)\leq 3$, then we can never contract an edge of the form $(u,v)$ where both $u$ and $v$ have degree at least $3$. This is because otherwise we would create a vertex of degree at least $4$ at this step, and since we are only now contracting edges joining two vertices of degree at least $2$, $H$ would then have a vertex of degree $4$.

So in forming $H$ from $G^\prime$, we are only contracting edges joining two vertices with at least one of the two vertices having degree exactly $2$. Thus $H$ is a topological minor.

Comment: There is something i'm not quite sure about here in this proof. Suppose we have vertices $u$ and $v$ as part of $G'=K_{4}$. Now both have degree $3$ and so have degree at least 3. Contracting the edge $uv$ into a single vertex does not however form a vertex of degree $4$. How do you account for this in your proof?

Comment: @PavanSangha I don't understand. What is $H$ in this case? Any minor of $K_4$ is a subgraph of $K_4$ and so can be obtained by only deleting edges/vertices, which you're supposed to have done before doing any contracting.

Comment: Ok your right in that case what about in the case where we have an edge $uv$ with $u$ and $v$ each of degree 3 which share a common neighbour $w$, then the vertex obtained from the contracted edge has degree three. In this case would we have deleted the edge from $u$ to $w$ in the previous stage, so that $u$ only has degree 2?

Comment: @PavanSangha I don't know? What is the $H$?

Comment: sorry $H$ is just any graph, i wasn't initially sure about your statement that if we contract an edge $(u,v)$ with $d(u),d(v) \geq 3$ that the resulting vertex $v'$ satisfies $d(v') \geq 4$ and i was trying to come up with a counter example. However in both cases where by we can contract an edge $uv$ with $d(u),d(v) \geq 3$ but $d(v') \leq 3$ it seems as if we can avoid this in the previous step by removing an edge or edges.